# Laravel, check if session array has value

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel

How do I check, if a value already exists within a Session array? I'm trying store active tree objects within a Session array to toggle them on and off:

```
public function postSelected()
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    if (Session::has('user.selection', $id)) { // check?
        Session::pull('user.selection', $id);
    } else {
        Session::push('user.selection', $id);
    }

    return Response::json(Session::get('user.selection'), 200);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what you're trying to do is akin to a toggle (remove if present, add if missing):

```
$index = array_search($id, $selection = Session::get('user.selection', []));

if ($index !== false)
{
    array_splice($selection, $index, 1);
}
else
{
    $selection[] = $id;
}

Session::set('user.selection', $id);
```

Comment: That easy! What are those brackets at the end of the session doing? Did the trick, thanks! I've already tried in_array, but I have't been successful.

Comment: @wiesson - Those brackets are short array notation (it's equivalent to `array()`, which creates an empty array). Basically, it ensures that you're dealing with an array.

Comment: The array_pull will not remove the desired item from my array. Anything special, I have to notice?

Comment: I've added Log::info($selection) before and after and it is still the same, also my tree won't update. (I'm storing strings, not integers, if this helps)

Comment: @wiesson - Whoops! `array_pull` works with keys, not values. I updated my answer.